# Display CompositeCollection of shapes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to display different shapes in one Canvas (I have a solution on multiple Canvases - but that does not let me select all shapes, so it is worthless). I put my shapes in a CompositeCollection and use multiple DataTemplates in one ItemsControl. However, the programm does not display the Shapes, instead it displays the Property Names in the location X,Y.

This is the collection:

```
        Page.Collection.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = Page.Lines });
        Page.Collection.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = Page.Rectangles });
        Page.Collection.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = Page.Circles });
```

This is part of the class page:

```
public class Page:ViewModelBase,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<Line> lines = new ObservableCollection<Line>();
    ObservableCollection<Rectangle> rectangles = new ObservableCollection<Rectangle>();
    ObservableCollection<Circle> circles = new ObservableCollection<Circle>();
    CompositeCollection collection = new CompositeCollection();
    public CompositeCollection Collection
    {
        get
        {
            return collection;
        }

        set
        {
            collection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Collection");
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Line> Lines
    {
        get
        {
            return lines;
        }

        set
        {
            lines = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Lines");
        }
    }
```

Here is the XAML:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Page.Collection}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas  IsItemsHost="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Background="Transparent">
                </Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Start.X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Start.Y}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="Page.Lines">
                <Line X1="{Binding Start.X}" 
                    Y1="{Binding Start.Y}"
                    X2="{Binding End.X}"
                    Y2="{Binding End.Y}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="Page.Rectangles">
                <Rectangle 
                    Width="{Binding Extend.X}"
                    Height="{Binding Extend.Y}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="Page.Circles">
                <Ellipse
                    Width="{Binding Extend.X}"
                    Height="{Binding Extend.Y}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: if you want to target specific type then `DataType` must be a type [`{x:Type somenamespace:Line}`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) otherwise it's treated as XPath

Comment: Please write this as an answer, then I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target specific class by `DataType` then you must specify type [`{x:Type ...}`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322(v=vs.110).aspx). Without that you target XML element as stated in [`DataTemplate.DataType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the template is intended for object data, this property contains the type name of the data object (as a string). **To refer to the type name of the class, use the x:Type Markup Extension**. If the template is intended for XML data, this property contains the XML element name. See the documentation remarks for details about specifying a non-default namespace for the XML element.

So your XAML should look like this

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type somenamespace:Line}">
    <!-- removed content -->
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type somenamespace:Rectangle}">
    <!-- removed content -->
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type somenamespace:Circle}">
    <!-- removed content -->
</DataTemplate>
```

where `somenamespace` is the namespace where `Line`, `Rectangle` and `Circle` classes are defined

```
xmlns:somenamespace="clr-namespace:Namespace.To.Your.Classes"
```